# 27 lines on a cubic surface - which proof is better?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

There is a famous fact that any smooth cubic surface has exactly 27 lines.

I am a undergraduate students who want to view some detailed proofs of this result. I know there are several different approaches to it. Can anyone recommend me a proof which is both beautiful and useful for my future math study?

Comment: there is an answer here https://www.quora.com/In-Algebraic-Geometry-why-are-there-exactly-27-straight-lines-on-a-smooth-cubic-surface.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "better" means to you? For instance, are you looking for quick and snappy, or something more moderately-paced? Are there methods you'd like to favor or avoid?

Comment: Maybe you already did it. but a fun way to start is to check there is 27 lines on a particular cubic surface, for example the Fermat cubic $X^3+Y^3 + Z^3 + W^3=0$.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for reminding me to be more specific...  I just want a proof contains some important ideas and results that can be used for further study of algebraic geometry, so I think it will not be too quick and dirty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a question on MathOverflow for interesting results in algebraic geometry that's both enticing and accessible to undergrads, and among the answers [this outline of a proof of the 27 line theorem is given](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20261).
In the comments, the author points to [a more detailed presentation (page 222)](https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/manetti/dispense/GeoAlgebrica(23dicembre2015).pdf), which unfortunately is in Italian.
(The link provided in the MO answer is dead, but I have linked to a more recent version of the same text here.)
Another commenter points to a few other sources for some of the more technical results used in the proof.